# Angular - Running if-statement inside of function

Tags: angular

In angular, I have the following html for objects:

```
<li class="first_column">
  <div class="my_item" *ngFor="let item of items ; let i = index">
     <div *ngIf="i % 2 == 0"> //Odd number
         <item-detail [item]="item"></item-detail>
     </div>                  
  </div>
</li>
<li class="second_column">
 <div class="my_item" *ngFor="let item of items ; let i = index">
     <div *ngIf="i % 2 == 1"> //Even number
         <item-detail [item]="item"></item-detail>
     </div>                  
 </div>
</li>
```

This works fine, but I feel like this is pretty inefficient as it has run twice in order to display them.

The function is the following:

```
item_display(data){         
    this.items = data;          
};
```

Is there a way to run the if-statement directly inside of `item_display` function and simply display the odd and even indexed item instead of running it twice like the current setup that I have?

**UPDATED:**

The reason why it is structured the way is because I am displaying the odd number objects in the "first_column" and even number objects in "second_column".

Comment: What exactly you want to do in the view(display)?

Comment: Sure, just copy the `data` over to a new array having the order you want.

Comment: @Henry Thank you for the reply. I think I can have the condition in the function. But I am not familiar with the angular syntax in terms of how to display them in the html. A sample code maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Why run it twice at all? From your logic the only thing different is the ngIf, item-detail component doesn't seem to care whether it's odd or even. If you have presentational aspects to show based on that odd/even number, put that in the component template?

```
<div class="my_item" *ngFor="let item of items ; let i = index">
  <item-detail [item]="item"></item-detail>
</div>
```

Comment: In OPs code first all the odd, then all the even records are printed. (Whatever odd and even really means)

Comment: Hi. I updated the question. What i meant by even and odd is that, let say I have 10 objects. Then I want to display all the odd number ones (0,1,3..) in the `first_column` and even number ones (2,4,6...) in the `second_column`.

Answer (score 0):

```
hey as you provided description for your question you can save on computation using logic like this

    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div ng-show="item % 2 == 0">{{item}}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div ng-show="item % 2 == 1">{{item}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have also written a small js fiddle to explain how it is done hope this answers your question
http://jsfiddle.net/bishtneha/63pyqm42/1/

you need not to write ng-for / looping twice it all can be done once and you can call your directive inside the ng-repeat accordingly.